# change variable value in each() function last iteration - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, each

Here is my fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aidadev/4hrgh2q7/7/).

So I will have multiple steps which should be animated one by one. And for making them animated one by one I used some `flag` variable. Depending on its value corresponding step should be animated.

But there is one issue - its value is not being changed in the first step and that's why when you click on 2 (from the timeline) only first step is being animated. The issue is in the below part when I'm animating each arrow one by one in each() function and `flag` variable value is being changed in last iteration of arrows:

```
var flag = 0;
function step_1(){
    jQuery(".step_1_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
    jQuery(".step_1 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

    var delay = 0;
    jQuery('.step_1 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var total = $('.step_1 .arrows span').length;
        $this.delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 100, function(){
            $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
            if (index === (total - 1)) {
                jQuery(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                flag = 1;
            }
        });
        delay += 100;
    });
}

jQuery(".step_2_nav").click(function(){
    step_1();
    console.log(flag); /* here flag returns 0 instead of 1 */
    step_2();
});
```

When I'm putting this part

```
if (index === (total - 1)) {
    jQuery(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
    flag = 1;
}
```

out of animate callback function flag's value is being changed to 1 but it happens immediately without waiting to last arrow's iteration and all 2 steps are being animated immediately.

What I'm missing here? Any ideas please?

Comment: $this.delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 100, function(){  /*  **this is a callback function**  */ } }), callback function is executing after step_2() function call. 
Because of this, flag value is remain 0.

Comment: @aidadev - pls check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it using **setInterval()**

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4hrgh2q7/13/)**

```
var counter_step1 = 0;
var counter_step2 = 0;
var step1Completed = false;
var timeDelay = 400; // set delay time accordingly

function step1() {

  $(".step_1 .label").addClass("active_label_text");
  var arrowCount = $(".arrows_down span").size();
  var myFisrt = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter_step1 < arrowCount) {
      counter_step1++
      $(".arrows_down span:nth-child(" + counter_step1 + ")").addClass("white_animated_arrow");
    } else {
      $(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass("active_bullet_point");
      step1Completed = true;
      clearInterval(myFisrt);
    }
  }, timeDelay);
}


function step2() {
  var arrowCount = $(".arrows_up span").size();
  var mySecond = setInterval(function() {
    if (step1Completed) {
      $(".step_2 .label").addClass("active_label_text");
      if (arrowCount > counter_step2) {
        $(".arrows_up span:nth-child(" + arrowCount + ")").addClass("white_animated_arrow");
        arrowCount--
      } else {
        $(".step_2 .bullet_point").addClass("active_bullet_point");
        clearInterval(mySecond);
      }
    }
  }, timeDelay);
}

function setAnimation(myVALUE) {
  step1();
  if (myVALUE == "STEP2") { step2();  }
}

$(".step_1_nav").on('click', function() {
  setAnimation("STEP1");
});

$(".step_2_nav").on('click', function() {
  setAnimation("STEP2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood well. What you want when Step 2 is the animation to run in reverse, right?

You can achieve this by using jQuery **reverse()**, as this:

```
jQuery(jQuery('.step_2 .arrows span').get().reverse()).each();
```

```js
var flag = 0;
function step_1(){    
    jQuery(".step_1_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
    jQuery(".step_1 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

    var delay = 0;
    jQuery('.step_1 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var total = $('.step_1 .arrows span').length;
        $this.delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 100, function(){
            $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
            if (index === (total - 1)) {
                jQuery(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                flag = 1;
            }
        });
        delay += 100;
    });
}

function step_2(){
    if(flag == 1){
        jQuery(".step_2_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
        jQuery(".step_2 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

        var delay = 0;
        jQuery('.step_2 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var total = $('.step_2 .arrows span').length;
            $this.delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 100, function(){
                $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
                if (index === (total - 1)) {
                    jQuery(".step_2 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                    flag = 1;
                }
            });
            delay += 100;
        });
    }
}

jQuery(".step_1_nav").click(function(){
    step_1();
});

jQuery(".step_2_nav").click(function(){
    step_1();
    flag = 1;
    console.log(flag);
    step_2();
});
```

```css
.step {
  margin-right:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.arrows {
  width:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.arrows_up {
}
.arrows span {
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s;
    transition: border-color 0.4s;
}
.arrows_down span {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrows_up span {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.label {
  color:#000;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:block;
  font-family:'Arial';
}
.bullet_point span {
    font-family:'Arial';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.step_2 .bullet_point {
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.step_2 .label {
  margin-top:5px;
}
.active_label_text {
  color:red;
}
span.white_animated_arrow {
    border-color: red;
}
.timer_nav {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
.timer_nav  span.timeline {
  color:#000 !important;
  cursor:text;
}
.timer_nav span {
  color:#000;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:'Arial';
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:0px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.timer_nav span:hover {
  color:red;
}
.active_bullet_point {
  color:red;
}
.timer_nav span.active_bullet_point {
  color:red;
}
.active_bullet_point span {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step step_1">
  <span class="label">STEP 1</span>
  <div class="arrows arrows_down">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bullet_point"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="step step_2">
  <div class="bullet_point"><span></span></div> 
  <div class="arrows arrows_up">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <span class="label">STEP 2</span>
</div>

<div class="timer_nav">
  <span class="timeline">Timeline</span>
  <span class="step_1_nav">1</span>
  <span class="step_2_nav">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I know about the reverse functionality. I just want when first bullet point becomes red, only in that case second animation should start. Now when you click on "2" from timeline, you will see that only first step stuff become red but second step stuff become red only if you double click on "2" as flag value is being changed only when you double click on it @JV Lobo

Comment: I see. I've edited my answer. You can set the flag at the beginning of step 1 function and call step 2 function just there, right?

Comment: No, step_2 should happen only when step_1 is finished, so that animation will look logical. @JV Lobo

Comment: I think I got it now. I've edited again. So I've only added flag = 1; calling step_1(); when you click on step 2 button. that's the behavior you are looking for, right?

Comment: No, like this both steps start animating together. My issue is to understand why flag value is not being changed in each() function's last iteration @JV Lobo

Comment: flag value is changed on last iteration, but when you click on step 2 button, you fire step_1 function and step_2 function at the same time, and step_1 is taking 100 milliseconds on each item, so when step_2 is fired, step_1 has not finished yet, so flag value hasn't changed yet. do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Specify an anonymous callback, and make step_1 accept it:

```
function step_1(callback){
    if(!callback) callback =function(){};
    jQuery(".step_1_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
    jQuery(".step_1 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

    var delay = 0;
    jQuery('.step_1 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var total = $('.step_1 .arrows span').length;
        $this.delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 100, function(){
            $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
            if (index === (total - 1)) {
                jQuery(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                callback();
            }
        });
        delay += 100;
    });
}
```

And call it :

```
jQuery(".step_2_nav").click(function(){
    step_1(step_2);
});
```

This is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hrgh2q7/15/#fork)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind like unsync animation,  you can just call your `step2` after `step1` finished, means put it inside your callback function in step1. 
I set `setTimeout` because seems you have ues extra transition, it will make your step1 call extra longer.

```js
    function step_1(child) {
        jQuery(".step_1_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
        jQuery(".step_1 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

        var delay = 0;
        jQuery('.step_1 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var total = $('.step_1 .arrows span').length;
            $this.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, delay, function() {
                $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
                if (index === (total - 1)) {
                    jQuery(".step_1 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                    if(child) setTimeout(()=> step_2(), 300);
                }
            });
            delay += 100;
        });
    }

    function step_2() {
        // if (flag == 1) {
            jQuery(".step_2_nav").addClass('active_bullet_point');
            jQuery(".step_2 .label").addClass('active_label_text');

            var delay = 0;
            jQuery('.step_2 .arrows span').each(function(index) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var total = $('.step_2 .arrows span').length;
                $this.delay(delay).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 100, function() {
                    $this.addClass('white_animated_arrow');
                    if (index === (total - 1)) {
                        jQuery(".step_2 .bullet_point").addClass('active_bullet_point');
                    }
                });
                delay += 100;
            });
        // }
    }

    jQuery(".step_1_nav").click(function() {
        step_1();
    });

    jQuery(".step_2_nav").click(function() {
        step_1(true);
    });
```

```css
.step {
        margin-right: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .arrows {
        width: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .arrows_up {}
    
    .arrows span {
        border: solid #000;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s;
        transition: border-color 0.4s;
    }
    
    .arrows_down span {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .arrows_up span {
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    
    .label {
        color: #000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Arial';
    }
    
    .bullet_point span {
        font-family: 'Arial';
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
        transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    
    .step_2 .bullet_point {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .step_2 .label {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    
    .active_label_text {
        color: red;
    }
    
    span.white_animated_arrow {
        border-color: red;
    }
    
    .timer_nav {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    
    .timer_nav span.timeline {
        color: #000 !important;
        cursor: text;
    }
    
    .timer_nav span {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
        transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    
    .timer_nav span:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .active_bullet_point {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .timer_nav span.active_bullet_point {
        color: red;
    }
    
    .active_bullet_point span {
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step step_1">
        <span class="label">STEP 1</span>
        <div class="arrows arrows_down">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bullet_point"><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="step step_2">
        <div class="bullet_point"><span></span></div>
        <div class="arrows arrows_up">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <span class="label">STEP 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timer_nav">
        <span class="timeline">Timeline</span>
        <span class="step_1_nav">1</span>
        <span class="step_2_nav">2</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done below thing this will work but not a correct method to resolve the solution.

This is happening because JS is not stopping until the step_1() is over. It is not waiting for 'delay' loop in step_1() and calling step_2(). If you put alert() in both functions you will come to know.

```
jQuery(".step_2_nav").click(function(){`enter code here`
      step_1();
      flag=1;
      step_2();
})
```

You also can try to use
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Hope so it will help